# <td> tag not showing up in html

Tags: html, html-table

Why is the second `< td>` not showing?
 I've tried the `inspect element` thing on google chrome and don't pick it up, all it sees the first one.
Tell me if I'm being specific enough.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>v1.0.0</title>
</head>
<body background="images/html/background001.png" bgcolor="6699ff">
<center>
<table>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#6699ff" width="660" height="500">
<iframe width="660" height="500" src="index.html" frameborder="0">browser said no<iframe>
</td>
<tr/>
<tr>
<td id="controls" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100" height="500">
<img src="images/html/controls.png">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<tr/>` should be `</tr>`

Comment: Please find a more modern guide to learn HTML from. This looks like it came out of the mid-1990s (with its lack of Doctype, and use of presentational attributes and layout tables). Your actual problem is caused by a simple missing character that a [validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/) would identify as a problem.

Comment: `<center>`. Don't use it.

Comment: center .. table .. iframe..   bgcolor, width, background and height tags.. Damn I feel young again! We are back in 1999! (All sillyness aside.. you should grab a web development book that was written in -this- millennium o.O

Comment: I have added an answer that might help you progress. This question will most likely be closed because it is too specific and will not be of help to other users of stackoverflow.com. Do not be discouraged by this, this is simply how stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your `iframe` tag.

```
<iframe width="660" height="500" src="index.html" frameborder="0">browser said no</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will fix your problems (closed td, closed iframe, as has been mentioned by others). I've only added this answer to give you some ideas on how to do things differently. It would be wise to jump into CSS as soon as you can. You are currently using methods that are out of practice these days.

Search for HTML5, CSS3 etc. Try to avoid using tables for layout purposes. Try to avoid using iframes all together.

One place to start would be http://learnlayout.com/

Good luck with learning!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>v1.0.0</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background: #6699ff url(images/html/background001.png);
            }

            td.iframeContainer {
                background-color: #6699ff;
                width: 660px;
                height: 500px;
            }

            iframe {
                width: 660px;
                height: 500px;
                border: 0;
            }

            td#controls {
                background-color: #fff;
                width: 100px;
                height: 500px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="iframeContainer">
                    <iframe src="index.html">browser said no</iframe>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="controls">
                    <img src="images/html/controls.png">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** I did a quick search for something that might help you get started on proper web development. This seems promising: http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/HTML5-CSS3-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners

ps. Not trying to sound degrading in any way. Old skool html layouts actually still have a place in html emails for example, but considering there is an iframe there I am guessing you were not working on an email template..